# NodeJS spawn process that is an alias

Tags: node.js, bash, alias, spawn

I'm trying to spawn a process from nodejs, with spawn from child_process.
But the command I'm trying to run is an alias inside the .bashrc file of the running user.

```
// index.ts or whatever
import { spawn } from "child_process";

spawn('cmdAlias', [args], {
  env: process.env,
  stdio: 'inherit',
  shell: '/bin/bash'
});

// .bashrc
[...]
alias cmdAlias='echo foo'
```

This doesn't work, it throws a command not found (cmdAlias).

If I try to reconfigure bash manually by running:

```
// index.ts or whatever
import { spawn } from "child_process";

spawn('source $HOME/.bashrc; cmdAlias', [args], {
  env: process.env,
  stdio: 'inherit',
  shell: '/bin/bash'
});
```

Then I get source command not found!

There a way to spawn a process with the aliases loaded?

*(note the alias works from terminal, that's a given)*

*PS: oversimplified examples here*

Comment: _I get source command not found!_  There is no executable named `source` in your PATH. Aside from this, alias-expansion is turned off by default for a non-interactive bash. If you need it in a shell script, you can turn it on with `shopt -s expand_aliases`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried these steps on my OS and it worked:

1. execute `nano ~/.bashrc`
2. Add `alias cmdAlias='echo foo'` to `.bashrc`
3. Now locate to your project and create these two files there

```
// ./cmdAliasWrapper
#!/bin/bash
echo "Running cmdAliasWrapper.sh"
bash -i -c "cmdAlias $*"
exit 1
```

```
// ./test.js
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

const args = [
    "echo 'This ran from test.js'"
];

spawn('./cmdAliasWrapper.sh', args, {
    env: process.env,
    stdio: 'inherit',
    shell: '/bin/bash'
  });
```

4. Execute `chmod +x ./cmdAliasWrapper.sh`
5. And finally `node ./test.js`

Now you should see this on your console:

```
Running cmdAliasWrapper.sh
echo foo This ran from test.js
```

Edit: We can do the same operation without a .sh file:

```
// ./test.js
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

const args = [
    "-i",
    "-c",
    "cmdAlias 'This ran from test.js'"
];

spawn('bash', args, {
    env: process.env,
    stdio: 'inherit',
    shell: '/bin/bash'
});
```

Comment: Remove the `source $HOME/.bashrc` . It doesn't do anything useful. .bashrc will be sourced anyway, since you are calling bash with `-i`.

Comment: @user1934428 Ah ok. Thanks for heads up. I'll update my answer

Comment: Actually, in your wrapper, if you write the sheebang as `#!/bin/bash -i`, you even don't need to create another bash inside. The `-i` reads .bashrc **and** turns on alias expansion.

Comment: Well yes that would work... but It will require me to do hacks and/or copy the .sh file around (I'm using typescript and I want to package it)... so I'm looking for a out of the box solution If possible.

Comment: @user1934428 That's true! 
@TazGR You can do the same operation without a `.sh` file. Please see my answer.

Comment: Just FYI: On StackOverflow, you can (unless this has been changed recently) notify in a comment only one single user with '@'. If you want to send notifications to two users, you have to somehow write two comments. I dislike this, but that's how this site is designed.